# Bash script not getting input variable

Tags: bash

I have a simple bash script, see below

```
#!/bin/bash

while getopts "t" opt; do
    case $OPT in
        t) JWT_TOKEN="$OPTARG"
            ;;
        \?) echo "Invalid option -$OPTARG" >&2
            ;;
    esac
done

echo "Token value is $JWT_TOKEN"
```

A simple test call is

```
my-script.sh -t 'test'
```

However this creates the following output

```
sedavidw@MacbookPro~$ sh my-script.sh -t 'test'
Token value is
sedavidw@MacbookPro~$
```

**UPDATE**
Was able to fix my script by changing it to

```
#!/bin/bash

while getopts "t:" opt; do
    case "${opt}" in
        t) JWT_TOKEN="$OPTARG"
            ;;
        \?) echo "Invalid option -$OPTARG" >&2
            ;;
    esac
done

echo "Token value is $JWT_TOKEN"
```

From the comments it looks like the `t:` change was helpful for the argument.  But still not clear on the syntax change for the `"${opt}"` part, and would like some clarity there

Comment: Almost right. From [man getopts](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/getopts.1p.html) `If a character is followed by a
                 <colon>, the option shall be expected to have an argument`

Comment: @KamilCuk to be clear you're suggesting it should be `while getopts "t:" opt; do`?  Because I've done that way as well and gotten the same result

Comment: `${...}` is a red herring. Variable names are case-sensitive. `$OPT` is not the same as `$opt`.

Comment: @sedavidw Post your `able to fix my script` as an answer. And then accept it ;) You passed `opt` in `getopts "t:" opt` so you need to do `case "$opt"` not `case "$OPT"`, the lower/upper-case matters. If you would have done `getopts "t:" OPT`, then `case "$OPT"` would work.